# How do I plot one of my categorical variables as either differennt colours or shapes using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm a beginner to R programming and mostly use it for basic data analysis for political science and economics and as such am familiar with only a very selective set of functions. That being said I was playing around with data visualization of India's COVID19 district level data from [here](https://api.covid19india.org/) and wanted to visualize "States" variable in different colors or shapes but it isn't happening.
Please help me out with this.

```
ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased)+ geom_point()
ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased),shape=States)+ geom_point()
ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased),col=States)+geom_point()
```

[The Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iDek.png)

Comment: You may want to include the  a minimal dataset for someone to assist

Comment: Just put `shape=States` or `color=States` inside `aes()`. And it's `State`, no plural.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Is this is the code ? 'ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased,shape=State)+geom_point())'           It is showing the following error message "Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`."

Comment: @Moses I can try uploading the raw data I'm using here. Is that what I'm supposed to do ?

Comment: @RadDragon Yes, post your data into the question using `dput(district_wise)`. If you have a moment read up [MRE] and [ask] for guidance on setting out questions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @RadDragon you may not necessarily post the whole dataset but rather a bare minimum that can be used to help. May be three variables and sample of 20 records can just do

Comment: Try with `ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased,shape=State))+geom_point()`. In your first comment you have put the `geom_point` inside `ggplot(...)` which gives the error you mentioned.

Comment: BTW: Using `shape` is not recommended and will not work as there are too many different states in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two plots one for points shapes by categorical variable `State_Code` and the other for colors by `State_Code`.
In the case of point shapes I first create a vector of shape numbers since `ggplot` only accepts 6 different shapes. The way to increase this number is with `scale_shape_manual`. And the values between 26 and 31 must be removed from the shapes vector, see `help("points")`.

```
library(ggplot2)

pch <- c(1:25, 33:127)
pt_shapes <- pch[1:length(unique(district_wise$State_Code))]

ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased,shape=State_Code)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=pt_shapes)

ggplot(district_wise,aes(x=Confirmed,y=Deceased,color=State_Code)) +
  geom_point()
```